# removing everything before comma using regex sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

If I have the following dataset in Sublime, how I can get the following expected output using regex operation.

Given dataset:

```
1,11111111
123,22222222
12,88888888
```

Expected output:

```
11111111
22222222
88888888
```

So, basically I would like to get rid of everything before comma in the comma itself.

What would be the regex expression to run in sublime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you could do it by finding index of last comma and taking substring from your orginal string, which I'd recommend, here isd pattern to use `(?<=,).++`.

`(?=,)` - assert that after current position there's comma.

`.++` - match as much characters as possible, except new line `\n` (since you want everything after the comma), unless you are using single line mode in regex.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFXbHC/1)

Comment: Could just do `\d+$` ?

Comment: @eurotrash That's an alternative, but incorrect. What if after last comma there could be other characters than digits? In general I would use character class `[wahtever characters you want]+$`.

Comment: The dataset is only digits, but fair enough if you want it to handle everything.

Comment: Great @MichałTurczyn, your solution solved my issue. And thanks for adding a demo

Answer (score 3):

Doing a `ctrl + f`, entering `\d+,`, pressing `alt + enter` and then `return`, you should get what you want.

Hope this help.

Comment: In the above case I mentioned, this solution doesnot work. It returns everything such as

1
11111111
123
22222222
12
88888888

Comment: You might have forgot the comma after `\d+` => `\d+,`, it work like a charm home.

Comment: you are right. I forgot the comma. Your solution also works for me. Appreciate it